# How to set background image in angular 6?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular6

Here i want to set placehoder image and for that i use commonurl path (this.commonUrlObj.commonUrl) instead of (http://localhost:3000) so how to set image in background-image using commonurl in angular 6?

category.component.html

```
<img [src]="url" style="height: 400px;width: 400px" [ngStyle]="{'background-image': getUrl()}">
```

category.component.ts

```
getUrl(){
  return "url('this.commonUrlObj.commonUrl/placeholder.jpg')";
}
```

common-class.ts

```
export class CommonClass {
  constructor(public commonUrl : string = 'http://localhost:3000'){};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand your problem but is this what you wanted to do ?

```
getUrl(){
  return `url('${this.commonUrlObj.commonUrl}/placeholder.jpg')`;
}
```

Comment: this part ${this.commonUrlObj.commonUrl} will not render, it will display as it is use ` instead, to the whole string

Comment: i use ` for whole string but it gives this type error GET (http://localhost:4200/%60$%7Bthis.commonUrlObj.commonUrl%7D/placeholder.jpg%60 404 (Not Found))

Comment: Oh yeah I missed the `` quotes  -> Edited
still dosen't work ?

Answer (score 3):

```
getUrl(){
  return "url('"+this.commonUrlObj.commonUrl+"'/placeholder.jpg')";
}
```

Comment: what give "getUrl()" ?

Answer (score 0):

You can't have an background image for an image. What you can do is wrap a `div` and give it an background:

```
getUrl(){
  return "url('"+this.commonUrlObj.commonUrl+"'/placeholder.jpg')";
}

<div  [ngStyle]="{'background-image': getUrl()}>
  <img [src]="url" style="height: 400px;width: 400px">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per docs in [Angular.io](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle) you can give ngStyle an ObjExp. Like this.

```
TS
// Not in the question but don't use a constructor to define vars
private commonUrl: string = 'localhost:3000'; // Could have this as an env variable

getBackground() {
   return {'background-image': `url(${this.commonUrl}/placeholder.png)`};
}

HTML
<div [ngStyle]="getBackground()"></div>
```